# Hire / Ask for Interested Collaborators on Programming Projects

Tags: feature-request

I know Stack Overflow itself isn't the place to ask if people are interested in collaborating or taking up a (or more) *paid* programming project (as freelance), so that's why I ask it here. Is there any way one can ask members in Stack Overflow if they are interested? It's really such a good network of programmers it will be such a waste not to tap into it. Otherwise, what other good networks are available?

Comment: Try [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: [main] isn't a forum. Go look for a forum that specializes in the tech stack that you're interested in using, and try ask in one of those. If you're project is interesting, you might even consider asking on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/news) or [Programming Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/), but be careful, those forums might regard what you're asking as spam.

Comment: They asked a reasonable question and didn't offend the users by just posting it.  I disagree with the downvotes here.  It discourages free discussions.  Give him a break.

Answer (score 8):

If a user is on Stack Overflow to look for a gig — and they have a good enough reputation — chances are they have a [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) profile. Or heck, look at their own profile. Do they list a portfolio site or something similar that provides contact info? Chances are they are doing that to get their name out there and network with other like-minded folks. It’s worth at least contacting them if they are willing to promote themselves that way.

In general — as someone who is open to hearing about gigs but also doesn’t jump at every offer — I don’t care to be contacted about every hairbrained (no disrespect, but let’s face it) project someone has. I tend to wait for something that makes sense for my skills, my interests and my scale.

I also think I am not the only one here to think that way, so don’t take it personally if you don’t hear back from someone right away. They might be just politely saying, “Hey, sorry… Not interested.” And if you don’t like the silence, politely contact them again a few weeks later — or whatever timespan feels right — but don’t demand “I will pay you! You must respond to me because I am impulsive!” for their skills. Respect will get respect.

Also, when you say this I understand where you are coming from, but I wince a bit:

> It's really such a good network of programmers it will be such a waste not to tap into it.

I am not here to be “tapped” into. I’m here to hone my skills, help others and — this is the career part — create a tangible/visible record of my technical knowledge.

A lot of this type of work is inherently invisible, so Stack Overflow allows invisible work to be visible. But I also don’t come here to get “hit on” for every idea someone might have.